# Material Design Lite sticky mini-footer truncated when used in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, material-design-lite

I am trying to implement a sticky footer within the material design lite framework. I have chosen to do this [using flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#article-header-id-3) since MDL uses it already and it is the most flexible and hack-free method I know.

```css
main.main-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.page-content {
  /*min-height: 500px;*/
}

div.mdl-layout__container{
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--no-drawer-button">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--waterfall mdl-layout__header--waterfall-hide-top" id="djpsych-header">
      <div class="mdl-layout-icon"></div>
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row" id="djpsych-header__top-row">
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <span class="mdl-layout__title"> Title of the site </span>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        some kind of navbar element
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <a id='top'></a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main class="mdl-layout__content main-layout">
      <div class="page-content">
        <p>This is the content of the page!</p>
        <p>This is the content of the page!</p>
        <p>This is the content of the page!</p>
        <p>This is the content of the page!</p>
        <p>This is the content of the page!</p>
        <p>This is the content of the page!</p>
        <p>This is the content of the page!</p>
        <p>This is the content of the page!</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="mdl-mini-footer">
        <div class="mdl-mini-footer__middle-section">
          <div class="mdl-logo">Title</div>
          <ul class="mdl-mini-footer__link-list">
            <li><a href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy & Terms</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The header may not render on the small preview screen. You can see that the bottom half of the footer gets truncated. This only happens when the content is taller than the viewport, otherwise the sticky footer fix works fine (try changing the `min-height` of the `.page-content` rule). I have noticed that in those cases, the height of the footer content becomes 0, but when the content of the `<div class="page-content">` does not fill the viewport, then the footer actually has a height. Is this a bug?

Note that the html of the footer is taken directly from the MDL docs.

http://codepen.io/rivasd/pen/PGagLP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material Design Lite sets `.mdl-layout__container`'s `height` to `100%`, impeding the ability of the inner elements to grow. This causes `.page-content` to overflow out of `.mdl-layout__content`, leaving zero room for the footer.

Get rid of that troublesome `height`!

```
.mdl-layout__container {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I removed the all height property declarations in the css, and simulated actual content. you can see the problem persists @darrylyeo

Comment: I've clarified my answer.

Comment: Implemented your answer, still no luck :( @darrylyeo

Comment: In fact, my rule was superseded by MDL, fixed and now your fix seems to work!

Comment: You are a genius @darrylyeo

Comment: it works but it breaks the waterfall header effect actually @darrylyeo